# Conditional variance problem

Tags: probability

Three people - Alice, Bob and Eve play a game. Every round, each of them tosses a fair coin. The one of the three who gets a different side of the coin wins the game. If three of them got the same side (for example three heads or tails), the game continues to the next round. There are up to 4 rounds. The game ends in a tie if there is no winner after the fourth round.

Probability for a person to win the game is $\cfrac{85}{{256}}$. A person can't lose the game, but it can end as a tie for everyone. They play the game 10 times (each game takes up to 4 rounds). If it is known that Alice won the game 4 times, what is the variance of games won by Bob?

My attempt was to use the conditional variance:

$Var(X|Y=4)=E[X^2|Y=4]-(E[X|Y=4])^2$

Where $X$ represents the games won by Bob, and $Y=4$ represents the 4 games Alice won (out of 10). So:

$E[X|Y=4]=\sum_{x=1}^{10}  x⋅P(x|y=4)$

Now I can sum over the iterations of x and calculate the probability of each $P(X=x|y=4)=P(X=x∩y=4)/P(y=4)$. I think that they are not independent, so I need to calculate the probability of $P(X=x∩y=4)$ for sure.

Then, I must also calculate $E[X^2|Y=4]=\sum_{x=1}^{10}  x^2⋅P(x|y=4)$

All that looks like an enormous work. I think that it is possible to solve it like that, but I'm sure there is a better way. May somebody give me a hint?

Comment: The results of the game are unclear, so before i may decide to read further, please make clear what does it mean that "*A person can't lose the game, but it can end as a tie for everyone*..."

Comment: Fixed. I hope now it soudns better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the letters $A,B,C$ for the three players Alice, Bob and Eve. One can model the given game as follows using the space $\Omega=\Omega_0^{\times 10}$, where $\Omega_0$ is the probability space with four elements $A,B,C$ and tie, where $A,B,C$ (corresponding to the win of the corresponding player in a "simple tossing game" with at most four rounds) have each the probability $85/256$, and where the tie has the remained probability $1/256=1/4^4$. It is convenient to denote by $B'$ the event in $\Omega_0$ consisting of $C$ and the tie. It has probability $(85+1)/256$.

An element of $\Omega$ is of the shape $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_{10})$, where the components $\omega_j$ are from $\Omega_0$.

Now we restrict inside this space to the subspace $\Omega'$ consisting of $10$-tuples $\omega$ with exactly four components equal to $A$. Let $S_\omega$ be the subset of $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ of the places with the component $A$. Then we can split $\Omega'$ in a natural manner in disjoint subsets $\Omega_S'$, indexed by subsets $S$ of $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$. (So $\omega\in\Omega'_S$ iff $S_\omega=S$.)

Now we fix such an $S$, and consider the given problem on $\Omega'_S$. By permutation symmetry we may and do assume $S=\{7,8,9,10\}$. Then on the remained places $1,2,3,4,5,6$
we can put independently either $B$ or $B'$. The two choices have weight $p=85/(85+86)$ and $q=1-p=86/(85+86)$. So we are dealing with a binomial distribution with parameters $n=6$ and $p=85/(85+86)$. The needed variance - restricted to $\Omega'_S$ - is
$$
n\;pq =6\cdot\frac{85\cdot 86}{(85+86)^2}\approx 1.4999487021647\dots\ .
$$
Since this does not depend on $S$, this is also the variance on $\Omega'$.

Comment: Thanks! But still, is my original way approaching this poblem is OK?

Comment: My solution above "computes" $P(\ (X=x)\cap(Y=4)\ )\ /\ P(Y=4)$ by finding the distribution of $X$ conditioned by $Y=4$. At some point in the solution we have to leave the "theoretical" way of writing general formulas that apply for any random variables $X,Y$ (with values in $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$) - as displayed in the posted question - and get dirty. Unfortunately, i don't see how to get/compute $P(x|y=4):=P(X=x|Y=4)$ from the last formula in the OP, last line, without getting/computing it explicitly... At some point, one has to work, get the hands dirty...

Comment: I still can't understand how to get the result $p=85/(85+86)$. It should be based on games won by B, but I don't know how exactly...

Comment: Let us fix one of the places $1,2,3,4,5,6$ in mind. On this place we have a choice of only $B$ and $B'$. (Recall that $B'$ is the event corresponding to a win of $C$ or a tie. Also, i am slightly abusively writing $B$ instead of the event $\{B\}$.) The probability for $B$ in that fixed place is a conditional probability, corresponding to $P_0(Z=B|Z\ne A)$, $Z$ being the random variable with values $A,B,C$ and tie on $\Omega_0$. Then $P_0(Z\ne A)=P_0(Z\in\{B,C,\text{tie}\})=\frac{85+85+1}{256}$, and $P_0(B)=\frac{85}{256}$. Now build the quotient...

Comment: Thank you very much!